# "status" of Product not have Publish option in Quick Edit with user role are "Editor"

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqNTK.png)I am using [User Role Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/) plugin with my WooCommerce site. To manage the products, I have 2 user roles, which are "Admin" and "Editor":

- Login with admin and the click on Quik Edit link and then select on Status option will have 3 option, Publish, Pending Review and Draft for users.
- But login with Editor account, the Publish not display and instead are scheduled option.

What I need help how to setup status of Editor account have publish option like Admin account.

[image]

Comment: For your user role "Editor", you can add capabilities by going to Users > User Role Editor, Select "Editor" Role. Then enable "edit_others_products",  "edit_private_products", "edit_product", "edit_products", "edit_published_products", "publish_products", "read_private_products", "read_product"... then UPDATE.

Comment: i'm ready enable these things, check here https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqNTK.png  but not have any change - still not see the Publish option

Comment: Then try to enable more options like shop_manager user role.

Comment: I'm assign full capabilities for user Editor like Admin role - then still not see the Publish option - its strange